# Form Navigation in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I have four JSP file say one.jsp, tow.jsp, three.jsp and four.jsp
each file has next and previous link to navigate to the all jsp's and last jsp file that is four.jsp has submit button. Now I want values of all fields from first three jsp's into the fourth one, to submit data into DB when the use hit the submit button from four.jsp
I do not have to use the hidden fields to pass the values from jsp to jsp and I don't want to use the session to store the data. Is there any way to pass the data(VO) from one jsp to another without using hidden fields and session?

NOTE : I am using spring. and I am not interested in JSF for navigation.

Comment: How about sending form data to controller and sending to next form as `modelAttribute` and so on?

Comment: yes Ajinkya, I am using modelAttribute to transfer the data. I have to pass the same modelAttribute to the next jsp, but it should be loaded with data filled in the previous form. Please let me know if you have any solution...

Answer (score 2):

So you need a stateful bean, might want to look into something like Spring Web Flow.  It was made for handling this sort of stuff.

If you don't want to store it in the session, you would have to start looking into EJB which has stateful possibilities.

Here's some documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/ejb.html

P.S. EJB stores stuff in the session as well, don't think there's any getting around it, unless you serialize the POJO and store it as a cookie.